# CPU, RAM or Motherboard? (PEBCAK!)

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure, troubleshooting

I have bought a bunch of used parts (like you do) and now of course they don't work well together, so I am diagnosing to find out which part(s) I need to swap.

- The mainboard is [Supermicro X9DRi-LN4F+](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X9DRi-LN4F_.cfm) ([manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C606_602/MNL-1258.pdf))
- The memory are 12 sticks of [Hynix 8GiB DDR3 ECC](https://www.skhynix.com/eolproducts.view.do?pronm=DDR3%20SDRAM&srnm=HMT31GR7CFR4C&rk=20&rc=module)
- The processors are 2 pieces of Intel Xeon E5-26xxv2 Confidential

Here is what I tested:

- I put the motherboard on the bench
- Attached one CPU in the first CPU slot
- Put one DIMM of memory in the first DIMM slot of the first CPU.
- Attached ATX power and both CPU power connectors from known working 750 Watt PSU
- Attached known working USB keyboard to USB slot in back panel of motherboard
- Attached VGA connector from VGA connector on back panel to bog standard, known working Benq 1080P flatpanel using a known working VGA cable.

I connected nothing else. There are no cards, wires or anything else connected.

I am familiar with proper handeling of the parts, how to keep them ESD safe, how properly seat CPU, RAM, heatsink and how to apply thermal compound etc.

I have swapped the CMOS battery for a new one and performed a CMOS reset according to the manual. I have also ensured all jumpers are in factory standard configuration.

[image: Bare setup]

When I switch on the PSU with this configuration and short the power button headers on the mainboard I make the following observations:

- The CPU fan and mainboard power led switch on indicating that the mainboard is indeed starting up
- The familiar num-lock light on the keyboard does NOT switch on. I verified that this light works by connecting the keyboard to another PC.
- There are no beeps
- The CPU fan runs in a slow speed for maybe 10-15 seconds before kicking in to a higher gear.
- The CPU does not become warm at all. It feels exactly like room temperature when I touch the base of the heatsink it is cold to the touch, even after several minutes.
- The screen remains in standby mode (orange light) and if I switch it on it proclaims "no signal found" before going back into standby.

I tried clicking caps-lock/num-lock buttons on keyboard, but this does not change the lights, which to me is disconcerting.

So from this configuration I made the following changes, completely removing power for each step:

- Removing the memory. This resulted in memory missing beep code (5 short one long) in accordance with manual. I take this as a sign the mainboard is not completely dead and it actually recognizes the memory properly.
- Putting memory in another DIMM slot. This had no effect what so ever.
- Trying different memory DIMMs. The seller of the DIMMs claim all were tested with memtest overnight and were in good working condition. I have no reason to not beleive him as he is a high profile seller with good reviews, but I tried at least 4 of the DIMMS all without any effect.

[image: Actual memory DIMM I am testing now]

- Trying the other CPU. To me the CPUs are the prime suspects at this point, but the seller claims they worked perfect in his Supermicro mainboard before he shipped them. He had no information on them beyond what is writte on them, and has kindly offered to take them in return if they don't work.

[image: Actual CPU I am testing now]

- Adding a known working dedicated graphics card (Nvidia GTX 1070) to PCIe slot 3 (first 16 lane slot for CPU 1). I attached the extra power cable directly from PSU and used a known good DVI cable to connect it to the monitor. I began to suspect maybe the VGA output was somehow not enabled. I read someplace that some VGA outputs require graphics support in the CPU to work. But this made no difference.
- Moving the dedicated graphics card to all 4 full length PCIe slots. No effect.
- Inspecting for schmoo or defects in the DIMM and CPU slots. I have a microscope for electronics that I used for this and they are squeeky clean and in perfect order.

[image: Under the microscope]

- Wiping gold contacts of DIMMs and CPU off with alcohol. No effect.
- Wiggling the DIMMs in the slot to ensure good contact. No effect.
- Singing a happy song to the setup. No effect.

So at this point I am looking for the **really pro tips**. How can I determine what is at fault? I don't have other motherboards, CPUs or memory laying around to test, so maybe someone with some Supermicro insights as to what I can test next to determine why my setup does not work could speak out!

I know there is some remote KVM and remote access to bios on this kind of card but I really don't know how to use it, and if it will be useful at all given I don't even get POST.

Any useful suggestion is welcome!

Comment: This CPU is an Engineering Sample (ES)... and to the best of my knowledge it's "_illegal_" to sell them (Intel have prosecuted people for handling them). They aren't supposed to leave Intel (or partner) labs, are pre-production quality and were intended to support the development process before being destroyed. They will likely be unstable. Try another CPU. :-)

Comment: @Attie Ah I didn't know that! Very useful information. Well that might be a big clue.

Comment: this may seem wierd but try using both CPUs at once. I super vagely remember something about needing a dummy CPU

Comment: Journeyman: Good tip! But manual stated just putting one CPU and one DIMM was recommended troubleshooting practice. I did test it, it had no success in my case. Hopefully it will save someone else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This CPU is an Engineering Sample (ES)...

- To the best of my knowledge it's "illegal" to sell them - Intel have prosecuted people for handling them.
- They are built explicitly for pre-production development and testing purposes, and always remain the property of Intel.
- They are used internally by Intel, and are loaned to OEMs and partners (probably under tight NDAs) for early testing and development with new systems, motherboards, etc...
- They are not production quality, and are intended to support the development process before being destroyed - they are likely unstable, not fully tested, and not feature complete

In summary... It's *probably* the CPU, I'd try another one before presuming it's good.

---

More information about Intel's Engineering Samples can be found here:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005719/processors.html

Comment: While I agree it's most likely the CPU, I wouldn't necessarily say it is because it's an ES. From the limited experience I've had with them (personally and otherwise), most of the ES were particularly stable and overclocked well. This makes some sense as Intel wants to ensure the OEMs receiving them for testing aren't getting duds and are probably binned somewhat high.

Any source on Intel prosecuting a regular Joe just in possession of an ES? I could definitely see them suing an OEM/employee for selling them, but a normal person?

Comment: The CPUs were indeed the culprit!

Comment: Sounds like you got it working? Good news :-)